# How to compare if a char or string variable equals a certain string?

Tags: c++, comparison, string-comparison, logical-operators

I'm trying to get this while loop to work but for some reason, it will automatically "assume" that the user input is wrong.

`value` is a string (should it be a char?)
`A`,`B`,`C` are strings (should they be char?)

```
void Course::set()
{
    cout << "blah blah blah" << endl;
    cout << "youre options are A, B, C" <<endl;
    cin >> value;

    while(Comp != "A" || Comp != "B" || Comp != "C") 
    {
        cout << "The character you enter is not correct, please enter one of the following: You're options are A, B, C" << endl;
        cin >> value;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: No, they shouldn't be `char`, `std::string` is great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an `&&` instead of an `||` in your condition. Currently, your condition is *always* true, because `Comp` can be equal to only one of three constants, but not all three at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other posted solutions, some might consider this more readable:

```cpp
while(! (Comp == "A" || Comp == "B" || Comp == "C"))
{
    // do something
}
```

Also, as others have pointed out, you probably intended:

```
cin >> Comp;
```

(Since you are using `Comp` not `value` in your `while` condition.)

Comment: This is also a great idea!! I need to try it

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you did there was thinking in the *daily usage of language* while building the `if` block. As others answered, you should use `&&` for the right logic.